# JOOQ transaction like jdbc

Tags: jooq

How to execute the transaction Manually in JOOQ? I didn't find it in jOOQ-manual-3.13.

ex:
  1. set autocommit = false
  2. start transaction
  3. when some thing happend(usually not error), rollback

Comment: Did you see this section? https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/

Comment: Sorry for my late replay, maybe my question is unclear,  I describe my problem in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771908/jooq-transaction

Comment: Thanks, I will look into your follow-up question. For the record, and for next time, you can edit questions here on Stack Overflow, in order to clarify things...