# JOOQ & Transaction

Tags: jooq

I have seen JOOQ [Transaction Management](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/) section
it's start transaction use jooq transaction api,

```
create.transaction(configuration -> {

    // Wrap configuration in a new DSLContext:
    DSL.using(configuration).insertInto(...);
    DSL.using(configuration).insertInto(...);
    
    // Or, reuse the new DSLContext within the transaction scope:
    DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(configuration);
    ctx.insertInto(...);
    ctx.insertInto(...);
    
    // ... but avoid using the scope from outside the transaction:
    create.insertInto(...);
    create.insertInto(...);
});
```

It's rollback is implicit.
But I want to submit and rollback by myself.
My project isn't base on Spring and Spring boot.
Is JOOQ has some api like this?

```
// start transaction
    api.begin()
// will do handle like this many times
    dslContext.update(...)
    Object obj = dslContext.select(...)
    if (obj == null) {
        api.rollback;
    }
    dslContext.insert(...)
    Object obj1 = dslContext.select(...)
    if (obj1 == null) {
        api.rollback;
    }
    ...
    ...
// finally, if no problem:
    api.commit
```

this section tell I can **implement your own org.jooq.TransactionProvider and supply that to your Configuration to override jOOQ's default behaviour**.
this interface method params is `TransactionContext`, I dont known what's this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Implicit transactions with jOOQ

You can use jOOQ's transaction API to achieve what you want to do like this:

```java
create.transaction(c1 -> {
    try {
        c1.dsl().transaction(c2 -> {
            c2.dsl().update(...);
            Object obj = c2.dsl().select(...);
            if (obj == null)
                throw new MyRollbackException();
        });
    }
    catch (MyRollbackException e) { ... }

    try {
        c1.dsl().transaction(c2 -> {
            c2.dsl().insert(...);
            Object obj = c2.dsl().select(...);
            if (obj == null)
                throw new MyRollbackException();
        });
    }
    catch (MyRollbackException e) { ... }
});
```

The above example is using implicit nested transaction using JDBC savepoints, whenever you create a nested `transaction()`. If you catch the exception that you're throwing yourself, then you won't roll back the entire transaction, but just the nested one.

Of course, it's possible to use a similar approach to roll back the entire transaction.

#### Procedural transactions with jOOQ

There's a pending feature request to add support for a procedural transaction API, similar to that of JDBC, in addition to the implicit lambda / exception based one that you've seen:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5376

Currently, you can't do what you intended with jOOQ alone, but you can always resort to using JDBC with jOOQ, e.g. (assuming `autoCommit = false`):

```java
// Obtain a JDBC connection from jOOQ (alternatively, use your own)
dslContext.connection(con -> {

    // Depending on your DataSource, make sure you're always using the same JDBC connection
    DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(con);

// start transaction
    // This isn't needed with JDBC, as a Connection always implicitly starts transactions
    // when autoCommit = false

// will do handle like this many times
    Savepoint sp1 = con.setSavepoint();
    ctx.update(...)
    Object obj1 = ctx.select(...)
    if (obj1 == null) {
        con.rollback(sp1);
    }
    Savepoint sp2 = con.setSavepoint();
    ctx.insert(...)
    Object obj2 = ctx.select(...)
    if (obj2 == null) {
        con.rollback(sp2);
    }
    ...
    ...
// finally, if no problem:
    con.commit();
});
```

Notice, I'm using JDBC `Savepoint` because I'm assuming from your example that this is what you want to do. If it's not, of course, you can just omit the savepoints and always roll back the entire transaction.

Comment: Thank you very much!   The second method is what i want, I'm becoming a big fan of JOOQ!

Comment: @caiRonald: Glad to hear that! :)